# How to increase the peak current to 12 kA in my circuit?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, inductor, switching, thyristor

I am simulating a circuit with a capacitor bank.  I am getting maximum peak current to 8.8kA.

I need to know how can I increase the peak current to 12-15 kA without increasing the input voltage. The input voltage must not be larger than 1000 V.

If I use 15 capacitors instead of 10 I am still getting the same results. I don't know why.

I am also posting the photo of my circuit. Please help me and tell me whether I need to change the values of the elements in my circuit.

[image: Simulated Circuit]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this design?

Comment: Oh my goodness, all my life I have been doing Micky Mouse projects, and my biggest  power supply is 12V and output 10A at most. You design of 1,000 V voltage and 15,000 A is unthinkable. Won't something melt down or explode?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question to explain why you are trying to do this and what problem you are trying to solve in plenty of detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome.

Comment: What does the discharge curve look like? (Current over time and voltage over time.)

Comment: @tlfong01:  Fortunately, LtSpice traces can carry infinite currents without heating and infinite voltages without arc over.   And its simulated loads don't explode when zapped too hard.

Comment: @JRE. I see, so LtSpice is just a imaginary tool to let you imagine the unimaginable.  I heard about MathLab but never LtSpice, need to Google later. I guess the OP is a mad scientist, trying to create a Small Bang, or a nano Black Hole. #Rajat Sharma, Keep on imagining! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOgFZfRVaww.